# Exchange 2010 - How to reset permissions on a public folder or remove it?

Tags: powershell, outlook, exchange-server

I have a public folder in my Exchange 2010 environment and I seem to not be able to remove the public folder because I do not have permissions..

Looking at the set permissions on the folder...

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-PublicFolderClientPermission -identity "\Marketing Contacts1" | fl

RunspaceId   : 13900165-2443-40c8-89a4-e74748eefe15
Identity     : \Marketing Contacts1
User         : Default
AccessRights : {Author}

RunspaceId   : 13900165-2443-40c8-89a4-e74748eefe15
Identity     : \Marketing Contacts1
User         : Anonymous
AccessRights : {None}

RunspaceId   : 13900165-2443-40c8-89a4-e74748eefe15
Identity     : \Marketing Contacts1
User         : vand1.oppy.com/Oppy/Wil/Janie Hewitt
AccessRights : {Owner}
```

Even if I try to log in with outlook as the Owner I still cannot pull up the "Security" tab on the public folder properties.

At this point I would like to either remove it and re-create it, or if there is a way to reset the permissions so that the administrator can work with the item.

I have access to the exchange server and administrative accounts. What can I do at this point now that I cannot manipulate the public folder item at all?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

`Remove-PublicFolderClientPermission -Identity "\Marketing Contacts1" -User "Name Of The User You wish to Remove Permissions from"`

Then you would set the admin you want to have owner permissions by doing this:

`Add-PublicFolderClientPermissions -Identity "\Marketing Contacts1" -User "Name of the user you wish to add permissions for"`